# How to remove "Double 512 vector" of multiArrayValue in Swift?

Tags: swift, coreml

I'm using CoreML in swift and I use this function to get the first vector.

> let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: visionModel) { request, error in
>               if let observations = request.results as? [VNCoreMLFeatureValueObservation],
>                   let output = observations.first!.featureValue.multiArrayValue

The problem is, when I print the output, it's contain "Double 512 vector" that I don't need it. How to remove those character cause I only use the vector. Don't need that string.

The output right now is: Double 512 vector
[0,0,0,8.003373659448698e-05,0,0,0.0007057895418256521,0.0001774219708750024,0,0,0,0]

The output I want is: [0,0,0,8.003373659448698e-05,0,0,0.0007057895418256521,0.0001774219708750024,0,0,0,0]

Thanks so much.